# Javascript HighCharts Pie color change not working

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have this `HighCharts` Pie Chart with 4 slices:

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    colors : ['#FD625E', '#69D7C6', '#573755', '#A3ABB7']
});

$('#pred_area_js').highcharts({
    chart : {
        type : 'pie',
        options3d : {
            enabled : true,
            alpha : 45
        }
    },
    title : {
        text : 'title'
    },
    subtitle : {
        text : 'subtitle'
    },
    plotOptions : {
        pie : {
            innerSize : 100,
            depth : 45,
            colors : ['#FD625E', '#69D7C6', '#573755', '#A3ABB7']
        }
    },
    series : [{
            name : 'chart name',
            animation : {
                duration : 2000
            },
            data : [
                ['Data1', 1634],
                ['Data2', 1403],
                ['Data3', 1085],
                ['Data4', 48]
            ]
        }
    ]
});
```

I tried many ways but It's using the default colors. And the 3D isn't working either. Can you tell me how should I use it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `Highcharts.setOptions` it will set the options for ALL charts on the page so maybe you have multiple charts on the same page.

For the 3d effect be sure to add the 3d script :

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-3d.js"></script>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/core972/09e88ror/) with colors and 3D effect working

Comment: Yes, you are right! i have multiple charts on the page.. But if i remove, the Highcharts.setOptions part, it's not working either...

Comment: @solarenqu , Use my fiddle and add the other chart to look if they all works or not

Comment: sorry, i was including <h:outputStylesheet name="css/highcharts.css"></h:outputStylesheet> after remove it's working.. Thank you!